# C# Nullable Annotation that method returns not null if parameter is not null

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, nullable-reference-types

How can I tell compiler that the following extension method returns not null if input is not null?

```cs
public static string? SomeMethod(this string? input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return input;

    // Do some work on non-empty input
    return input.Replace(" ", "");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to "tell" something to the compiler?

Comment: I think you are already telling the compiler that by writing this code LOL

Comment: Put `[return: NotNullIfNotNull("input")]` before the mehtod.

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT This is part of nullable references where you don't want the compiler to complain that something is null when you know it isn't and the compiler cannot figure that out without an attribute.

Comment: @Zee No the compiler will not know that the method will return a non-nullable string unless you tell it with an attribute.

Comment: @juharr thanks, never knew that this existed, long time without coding C#

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the following attribute:

```cs
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(input))]
public static string? SomeMethod(this string? input)
{
   ...
}
```

For further reading: [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

Comment: Thanks, was harder to find that article than anticipated!

Comment: Starting with C# 11 you can use `nameof` in the attribute like so `[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(input))]`

Comment: Note for people like me that wanted to apply this to async methods, it currently isn't supported to apply `NotNullIfNotNull` on `async Task<T?>` return types :(
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2793